# Can't get Lotka-Volterra equations to oscillate stable with math.js

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to implement a simple Lotka-Volterra system in JavaScript, but get different result from what I see in academic papers and slides. This is my equations:

```
sim2.eval("dxdt(x, y) = (2 * x) - (x * y)");
sim2.eval("dydt(x, y) = (-0.25 * y) + (x * y)");
```

using coefficients a = 2, b = 1, c = 0.25 and d = 1. Yet, my result looks like this:

[image]

when I expected a stable oscillation as seen in these [PDF slides](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/11809LV.pdf):

[image]

Could it be the implementation of ndsolve that causes this? Or a machine error in JavaScript due to floating-point arithmetic?

**Edit**: Disregard, the error was simply using a too big evaluation step (dt = 0.1, must be 0.01 at least).

Comment: I don't this question is appropriate for this community. MSE is for math questions, not programming questions.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Then you should vote to close it. :)

Comment: I'll let the community to decide. I only tried to suggest you that you're probably more likely to get a good answer on some other SE community.

Comment: OK, they had a `math.js` tag on stackoverflow, so I posted it there.

Comment: Or you should use a better method than the Euler method. Which means you would have to extend the ndsolve script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a well-known property of the Euler method that it is expansive for systems that have concentric convex trajectories. The Euler step moves forward in the direction of the tangent, and for a convex shape that tangent points outwards. Which means amplitudes increase.

Use a better method than Euler, Euler is nice if you learn to understand the theory of differential equations and their numerical methods, for real work use fixed-step RK4. Why RK4? If you go the step to multi-stage methods, that is to any serious method at all, then the step to the classical Runge-Kutta method is mostly just copy-paste. And there are no higher order method that look as simple.

Comment: Awesome, I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: Contrary to the strong points above, start with [Heun's order 2 trapezoidal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method) as proof-of-concept for a multi-stage method. When that works it is really mostly copy-paste and inserting the correct constants to get to RK4.

Comment: Oh, I will for sure copy-paste the code from somewhere.